# Describing sample space of given experiments

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> The question is to describe the sample space for the experiment of
> randomly picking an arc from a circle and this defining of $\Omega$
> should be done in two ways.

I really don't understand the experiment. I can choose an arc in infinitely many ways. The length of an arch can be given by

$$\ell=\frac{\theta 2\pi r}{2\pi} = r\theta.$$

Thus the sample space becomes

$$\Omega=\{r,\theta : \theta\in(0,2\pi], \ r=\text{constant in } \mathbb{R}^+\}.$$

Is this what they are looking for? Also, what is the other way?

Comment: You can also have picked $2$ angles instead of $1$ angle and the length.

Comment: Ah, ofcourse. So another sample space is $$\{\theta,\phi : \theta\neq \phi, (\theta, \phi)\in(0,2\pi]\}.$$

Comment: Why did you choose $r$? Aren't we talking about a given circle? And is the angle subtended at the centre of a circle sufficient to determine an arc uniquely?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri - Yeah maybe I did not need to choose $r$ but it was just to make it clear that $r$ can be any constant. It should be sufficient to determine it uniquely, since if I have $r$, choosing any $\theta\in(2\pi]$ I will obtain a length of an arc. However, this arc is only measured from "the positive x-axis". By introducing a new angle $\phi\neq\theta$ then any arc is uniquely determined. Please correct me if my reasoning is flawed.

Comment: Using only the central angle we can determine the **length** of an arc uniquely, true, but not the arc itself. For example, the minor arcs of the unit circle between angles $0,\pi/4$ and $\pi/4,\pi/2$ have the same length but they are not the same arcs.

Comment: And the arc is **not** uniquely determined by two bounding angles. This is because we can be talking about the minor or major arc.

Comment: You are right about the length vs arc part and I also understand why given your counter-example. I need to think more bout that part. About the major/minor arc: also correct, but how can I in my set point out that we only measure counterclockwise?

Comment: Moreover the length/central angle of an arc does not indicate whether the arc contains its end points.

Comment: You can explicitly mention that the arc is measured clockwise/anti-clockwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The central angle of an arc uniquely determines its length, but not its position. Minor arcs between $0,\pi/4$ and $\pi/4,\pi/2$ have the same length but they are not the same arc.

Choosing two bounding angles of the arc does not indicate whether we are talking about the minor or major arc bounded between the angles.

Both the above methods don't differentiate between an arc that contains its end points and one which doesn't.

---

One method to create the sample space is to use the bounding angles with an interval-esque notation along with explicitly stating that we are measuring the arcs anti-clockwise.

So $(\pi/4,\pi)$ denotes the arc from $\pi/4\to\pi$ where the end points are not included, like an open interval. But $[\pi/4,\pi]$ is the same arc plus its end points. $[\theta,\theta]$ denotes the minor arc that contains only one point, $[\theta,\theta),(\theta,\theta]$ denote the entire circle, $(\theta,\theta)$ denotes the major arc excluding one point. The issue here is that the entire circle is denoted by multiple sample space points.

So the sample space is$$S=\{[\theta_1,\theta_2],(\theta_1,\theta_2):\theta_{1,2}\in[0,2\pi)\}\cup\{[\theta_1,\theta_2),(\theta_1,\theta_2]:\theta_{1,2}\in[0,2\pi),\theta_1\ne\theta_2\}\cup\{[0,0)\}$$

I am not sure how relevant differentiating between an arc that does and does not contain its end points is to your example.